# How do I make a detailTextLabel show in my UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I know that I have to change the cell to a initwithstyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle, but the way that I created a cell seems to be different from a lot of the other questions I saw about this topic. Where exactly and how would I change the cell?

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self)
    {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"PasswordPrototypeCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Password *password = [self.passwords objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = password.itemName;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = password.passwordText;

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Are you using storyboard? and a table with a prototype cell?

Comment: Yes, but the information for the prototype cell only shows up when I click on and hold the cell. For the actual data displaying, I think it ignores the prototype cell and uses the default cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to make `initWithStyle` like this bellow

```
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
                               reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    } 

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"foo";

}
```

Comment: When I replaced the method with this, it says 'autorelease' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode. It also says ARC forbids explicit message send of 'autorelease'

Comment: remove autorelease from the code check my updated answer

Comment: Thank you! This fixed the problem. Does it matter if I make the cellidentifier @"PasswordPrototypeCell" instead of @"Cell"?

Comment: cell is only identifier declaration. you can use any that you want no issue with PasswordPrototypeCell

Comment: One more question: does it matter if the data for the detailTextLabel is the text from a textView or from a textField? Because I got it working for one page of my application, but it doesn't work for a similar page even though the code is almost exactly the same. The strings are getting stored, but the table only displays the main textLabel instead of the detailTextLabel.